# How do I make an "empty" anonymous function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I use anonymous functions for diagnostic printing when debugging in MATLAB. E.g.,

```
debug_disp = @(str) disp(str);
debug_disp('Something is up.')
...
debug_disp = @(str) disp([]);
% diagnostics are now hidden
```

Using `disp([])` as a "gobble" seems a bit dirty to me; is there a better option? The obvious (?) method doesn't work:

```
debug_disp = @(str) ;
```

This could, I think, be useful for other functional language applications, not just diagnostic printing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could add a regular do-nothing function to your codebase.

```
function NOP(varargin)
%NOP Do nothing
%
% NOP( ... )
%
% A do-nothing function for use as a placeholder when working with callbacks
% or function handles.

% Intentionally does nothing
```

Then you can use a function handle to it instead of to an anonymous function wherever you want to no-op something out.

```
debug_disp = @NOP;
```

Now it's somewhat self-documenting, making it explicit that you intended to do nothing, instead of grabbed the wrong input for disp(). It will be apparent in the source code, plus, when you're in the debugger and examining variables holding function handles, it'll show up as "@NOP", which may be more readable than an anonymous handle. And you can get a list of all nopped-out operations in the "profile report" output by looking at a list of callers to NOP.

You could also use Matlab's built-in @deal, which in the degenerate case does nothing and returns nothing.

Comment: I like this approach best. Despite the extra effort, I think it is indeed the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: On my machine, this approach is faster than all but two versions I tried. 1 million calls to handle() when handle was `handle=@NOP` required 7.09 seconds. Whereas `handle=@()[];` required 23.2 seconds. I imagine this is because of the overhead of object creation. `handle=@() drawnow('update');` required 3.37 seconds. `handle=@() disp([]);` and `handle=@() disp('');` were tied at 9.71 seconds. The fastest function was `handle=@() (1);` with a time of 0.775 seconds. Its calls, however must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Oops `handle=@() drawnow('update');` took 34.0 seconds for a million calls. I accidentally left out a 0 when typing 1000000. By the way, that is still much faster than `handle=@() drawnow;` - which took 187 seconds.

Comment: In R2015a I found the fastest of @Eponymous's suggestions was the nop function, implemented in same m-file as the calling function. This took 4.72s for 1 million calls on my machine. However, a slightly faster implementation was to create a nop mex function (which similarly does nothing). This took 3.39s.

Comment: FYI, in my codebase I'm now taking the approach of calling this function `pass` because that's the term that Python uses for the equivalent statement.

Answer (score 12):

I think `disp([])` or `disp('')` is perfectly acceptable. It doesn't return anything and it has no side effects.

Comment: I interpreted this as `@(varargin) disp('')` and this is the most concise, do-nothing function I have seen (that tolerates any number of inputs).

Answer (score 3):

If you're simply looking for a "do-nothing" command to replace the body of the anonymous function, I'd probably go with [DRAWNOW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html):

```
debug_disp = @(str) drawnow;
```

This will simply flush the event queue and update the graphics instead of displaying any text.

Comment: `drawnow()` events incur a performance hit if you have open graphics windows.

Comment: @shabbychef: If you don't want to update graphics, you can use `drawnow('UPDATE')`.

Comment: @gnovice: it is important to use lowercase for the string `drawnow('update')`, otherwise Matlab complains about "Unknown command option"

Answer (score 3):

Here's a do-nothing anonymous function. It does nothing, and returns an empty array, which you can just ignore. You'll need to suppress disp by putting a semicolon after it.

```
debug_disp = @(str) [];
```

The disp([]) should work fine too. Whichever style you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

try `debug_disp = @(str)(1);`

Comment: the comment [@Andrew Janke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904972/how-do-i-make-an-empty-anonymous-function-in-matlab/1907943#1907943) made also applies here: if you do it this way, all your calls to `debug_disp` need to be terminated by a semicolon, otherwise MATLAB will display `ans = 1` :-(.